# Symfony not create file by touch( )

Tags: php, symfony, filesystems, symfony-filesystem

I want to creat file this path : /var/logs/filename.fileextension . But ı dont create file ı have error ->Failed to touch "/var/logs/file.txt".

My Codes:

```
$fs=new Filesystem();
$fs->touch('/var/logs/file.txt');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> touch() sets access and modification time for a file. The current time
>   is used by default. You can set your own with the second argument. The
>   third argument is the access time:

**So touch doesnt create a new file according to the docs.**

read http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html

if you want to create a file you need to use the function dumpFile();

> dumpFile() allows you to dump contents to a file. It does this in an atomic manner: it writes a temporary file first and then moves it
>   to the new file location when it's finished. This means that the user
>   will always see either the complete old file or complete new file (but
>   never a partially-written file):

read http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html

This code should create a new empty file.

```
$fs=new Filesystem();
$fs->dumpFile('/var/logs/file.txt', '');
```

Comment: thank u Raymond its work :)
$fs->dumpFile($this->cont->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../var/logs/file.txt','content');

Comment: Symfony Filesystem [touch method](https://github.com/symfony/filesystem/blob/3.4/Filesystem.php) (in 3.4 at least) uses the php function touch() which does create a file according to [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php). Usually it fails because of permission issues. It also happened to me because I tried creating a file inside a non-existing directory.